# Is there a way to represent headlines in the same page?

Tags: header-footer

I get the required results for tables in appendix as shown here:[image]

The only problem here is that the headlines are shown in the previous page in a messy way as can be shown here:
[image]

How can I fix it so that the header will be on the same page?
I use the [amcs](https://www.amcs.uz.zgora.pl/?action=guide)template. And this is my code:

```
 \documentclass{amcs}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\newcommand{\tvar}[2]{%
    \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{appendices}
        {\\Appendix: Accasddy of SSSS accuracy vs. efdsf mFDsfd vooo (3 digit format)} \label{appendix:AppendixA}   
        \begin{table}[H]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=2.0] 
                    S[table-format=1.3] 
                    S[table-format=1.4] c c c }
                \toprule
                \thead{Dataset}  
                &   {\thead{Number\\ of Sfghes}} 
                &   {\thead{Efffffff 748\\ Accuracy}}
                &   {\thead{Syyy 448\\ Accuracy}}
                &  \thead{Difference}
                &   \thead{P-value}
                &   \thead{Tssssss  \\ Ssss }                 \\ 
                \midrule
                Ppppp & 32  & 0.632 & 0.592 & -0.04  &  \textless0.001 & 100000  \\ 
                Ppppp & 64  & 0.594 & 0.566 & -0.028 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\ 
                Ppppp & 128 & 0.537 & 0.533 & -0.003 &  0.051 & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                Ppppp & 256  & 0.499 & 0.521 & 0.022  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
                Ppppp & 512  & 0.499 & 0.525 & 0.026  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
                Ppppp & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.484 & -0.014 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                SSSS & 32   & 0.543 & 0.788 & 0.245   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
                SSSS & 64   & 0.543 & 0.786 & 0.242   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
                SSSS & 128  & 0.543 & 0.783 & 0.239   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
                \addlinespace
                SSSS &  256 & 0.543 & 0.778 & 0.234  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
                SSSS &  512 & 0.543 & 0.772 & 0.228  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
                SSSS &  1024& 0.781 & 0.767 & -0.013 &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
                \addlinespace
                RRRR &  32  & 0.781 & 0.767 & -2E-05 &  0.281    & 100000 \\
                RRRR &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 &  0.137    & 100000 \\
                RRRR &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -6E-05 &  0.144    & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                RRRR &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -4E-05  &  0.327 & 50000  \\
                RRRR &  512 & 1     & 1     &    0    &  -     & 10000  \\
                RRRR &  1024& 1     & 0.999 & -0.0002 &  0.078 & 10000  \\
                \addlinespace
                KKK CCC &   32  & 0.998 & 0.993 & -0.005  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   64  & 0.997 & 0.997 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   128 & 0.996 & 0.995 & -0.001  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                \addlinespace
                KKK CCC &   256 & 0.995 & 0.993 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   512 & 0.988 & 0.987 & -0.001 &  0.036   & 50000  \\
                KKK CCC &   1024& 0.984 & 0.984 & 1E-04  &  0.477   & 10000  \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}

            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{ c S[table-format=2.0] 
                    S[table-format=1.3] 
                    S[table-format=1.4] c c c}
                \toprule
                \thead{Dataset}  
                &   {\thead{Number\\ of Ssssss}} 
                &   {\thead{Eeeeeeee CCCC\\ Aaaaaaaa}}
                &   {\thead{Ssss CCCC\\ Aaaaaaaa}}
                &  \thead{Difference}
                &   \thead{P-value}
                &   \thead{Ttttttt  \\ Ssss }                  \\ 
                \midrule
                Ppppp & 32  & 0.563 & 0.549 & -0.014 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
                Ppppp & 64  & 0.550 & 0.542 & -0.007 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
                Ppppp & 128 & 0.536 & 0.533 & -0.003 & 0.096    & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                Ppppp & 256  & 0.521 & 0.504 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
                Ppppp & 512  & 0.499 & 0.486 & -0.013 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
                Ppppp & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.471 & -0.027 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                SSSS & 32   & 0.791 & 0.784 & -0.006 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
                SSSS & 64   & 0.787 & 0.779 & -0.008 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
                SSSS & 128  & 0.781 & 0.769 & -0.012 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
                \addlinespace
                SSSS &  256 & 0.781 & 0.765 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
                SSSS &  512 & 0.781 & 0.756 & -0.025 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
                SSSS &  1024& 0.781 & 0.751 & -0.03  &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
                \addlinespace
                RRRR &  32  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
                RRRR &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
                RRRR &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 & 0.222 & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                RRRR &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 50000  \\
                RRRR &  512 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-04  & 0.352    & 10000  \\
                RRRR &  1024& 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.0003  & 0.182    & 10000  \\
                \addlinespace
                KKK CCC &   32  & 0.992 & 0.990 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   64  & 0.987 & 0.987 & 0      & 0.5      & 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   128 & 0.987 & 0.987 & -8E-05 & 0.455    & 150000 \\
                \addlinespace
                KKK CCC &   256 & 0.987 & 0.987 & 2E-05  & 0.488 & 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   512 & 0.984 & 0.984 & 0.0003 & 0.431 & 50000  \\
                KKK CCC &   1024& 0.984 & 0.998 & 0.0139 &\textless0.001& 10000  \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table} 
    \end{appendices}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile, as there are some packages, like `booktabs` and `siunitx` , are missing, as well as probably some macro definitions, like the one of `\thead` (or it's in another package). Please complete your (non-)working example.

Comment: Have you tried with the `longtable` environment from the `ltxtable` package ?

Comment: Your table environment is too large to place on the same page, that is why it is o the next (it has to go somewhere). Since it is already two tabulars try to split it into two table environments, that will make it easier to place. Also do not use `[H]` since it limits the possibilities for float placements. Try `[htbp]`.

Comment: Thanks to all.  gernot - As for the code I added the required definition.  Jérôme - can you please elaborate? StefanH - Thanks a lot, but when I changed it to [htbp] and to table* the header is still in different page.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code so the tables are split into two pages. I added [htbp] and changed only the second table to {table*}.
[image]
[image]
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{amcs}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newcolumntype{C}\[1\]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\newcommand{\tvar}\[2\]{%
    \mathrm{#1}_{\mathrm{#2}}%
}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{appendices}
        {\\Appendix: Accasddy of SSSS accuracy vs. efdsf mFDsfd vooo (3 digit format)} \label{appendix:AppendixA}   
        \begin{table}\[htbp\]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{ c S\[table-format=2.0\] 
                    S\[table-format=1.3\] 
                    S\[table-format=1.4\] c c c }
                \toprule
                \thead{Dataset}  
                &   {\thead{Number\\ of Sfghes}} 
                &   {\thead{Efffffff 748\\ Accuracy}}
                &   {\thead{Syyy 448\\ Accuracy}}
                &  \thead{Difference}
                &   \thead{P-value}
                &   \thead{Tssssss  \\ Ssss }                 \\ 
                \midrule
                Ppppp & 32  & 0.632 & 0.592 & -0.04  &  \textless0.001 & 100000  \\ 
                Ppppp & 64  & 0.594 & 0.566 & -0.028 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\ 
                Ppppp & 128 & 0.537 & 0.533 & -0.003 &  0.051 & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                Ppppp & 256  & 0.499 & 0.521 & 0.022  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
                Ppppp & 512  & 0.499 & 0.525 & 0.026  &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
                Ppppp & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.484 & -0.014 &  \textless0.001 & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                SSSS & 32   & 0.543 & 0.788 & 0.245   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
                SSSS & 64   & 0.543 & 0.786 & 0.242   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
                SSSS & 128  & 0.543 & 0.783 & 0.239   &  \textless0.001& 500000   \\
                \addlinespace
                SSSS &  256 & 0.543 & 0.778 & 0.234  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
                SSSS &  512 & 0.543 & 0.772 & 0.228  &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
                SSSS &  1024& 0.781 & 0.767 & -0.013 &  \textless0.001 & 500000 \\
                \addlinespace
                RRRR &  32  & 0.781 & 0.767 & -2E-05 &  0.281    & 100000 \\
                RRRR &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 &  0.137    & 100000 \\
                RRRR &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -6E-05 &  0.144    & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                RRRR &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -4E-05  &  0.327 & 50000  \\
                RRRR &  512 & 1     & 1     &    0    &  -     & 10000  \\
                RRRR &  1024& 1     & 0.999 & -0.0002 &  0.078 & 10000  \\
                \addlinespace
                KKK CCC &   32  & 0.998 & 0.993 & -0.005  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   64  & 0.997 & 0.997 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   128 & 0.996 & 0.995 & -0.001  &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                \addlinespace
                KKK CCC &   256 & 0.995 & 0.993 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   512 & 0.988 & 0.987 & -0.001 &  0.036   & 50000  \\
                KKK CCC &   1024& 0.984 & 0.984 & 1E-04  &  0.477   & 10000  \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
\end{table}

    \begin{table*}\[htbp\]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{ c S\[table-format=2.0\] 
                    S\[table-format=1.3\] 
                    S\[table-format=1.4\] c c c}
                \toprule
                \thead{Dataset}  
                &   {\thead{Number\\ of Ssssss}} 
                &   {\thead{Eeeeeeee CCCC\\ Aaaaaaaa}}
                &   {\thead{Ssss CCCC\\ Aaaaaaaa}}
                &  \thead{Difference}
                &   \thead{P-value}
                &   \thead{Ttttttt  \\ Ssss }                  \\ 
                \midrule
                Ppppp & 32  & 0.563 & 0.549 & -0.014 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
                Ppppp & 64  & 0.550 & 0.542 & -0.007 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\ 
                Ppppp & 128 & 0.536 & 0.533 & -0.003 & 0.096    & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                Ppppp & 256  & 0.521 & 0.504 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
                Ppppp & 512  & 0.499 & 0.486 & -0.013 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
                Ppppp & 1024 & 0.499 & 0.471 & -0.027 &\textless0.001& 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                SSSS & 32   & 0.791 & 0.784 & -0.006 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
                SSSS & 64   & 0.787 & 0.779 & -0.008 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
                SSSS & 128  & 0.781 & 0.769 & -0.012 &\textless0.001& 500000   \\
                \addlinespace
                SSSS &  256 & 0.781 & 0.765 & -0.016 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
                SSSS &  512 & 0.781 & 0.756 & -0.025 &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
                SSSS &  1024& 0.781 & 0.751 & -0.03  &\textless0.001& 500000 \\
                \addlinespace
                RRRR &  32  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
                RRRR &  64  & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-05 & 0.44  & 100000 \\
                RRRR &  128 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -5E-05 & 0.222 & 100000 \\
                \addlinespace
                RRRR &  256 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -0.0007 &\textless0.001& 50000  \\
                RRRR &  512 & 0.999 & 0.999 & -1E-04  & 0.352    & 10000  \\
                RRRR &  1024& 0.999 & 0.999 & 0.0003  & 0.182    & 10000  \\
                \addlinespace
                KKK CCC &   32  & 0.992 & 0.990 & -0.002 &\textless0.001& 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   64  & 0.987 & 0.987 & 0      & 0.5      & 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   128 & 0.987 & 0.987 & -8E-05 & 0.455    & 150000 \\
                \addlinespace
                KKK CCC &   256 & 0.987 & 0.987 & 2E-05  & 0.488 & 150000 \\
                KKK CCC &   512 & 0.984 & 0.984 & 0.0003 & 0.431 & 50000  \\
                KKK CCC &   1024& 0.984 & 0.998 & 0.0139 &\textless0.001& 10000  \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table*} 
    \end{appendices}
    \end{document}
```